# XAMPP appache doesn't start automatic due to net

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, xampp

So when I restart my virtual machine my XAMPP apache server is blocked from starting automatic (it used to start automatic), and I can only start it after I've ran CMD as administrator and ran: `net stop was /y`

Why do I have to stop this? Is it some kind of windows feature I might have enabled without knowing (dont think I use it if so), or is there a way to bypass this blocking? Because every 2nd week the server is maintained and restarted, and then the website is down untill I do this fix..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running IIS which allocates the same TCP ports that Apache tries to (failing).

Either deactivate IIS altogether, change its service ports to something else, or bind both IIS and Apache to separate IP addresses.

Comment: Removed IIS, since I don't use it, and now everything works. Thanks!